# Inequality of complex numbers involving modules

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $|z| \ge 1$. Show that
$$\sqrt[6] \frac {|2z-1|^2} {7} \ge \sqrt[7] \frac {|z-1|^2} {3}.$$
My try: I wrote $|z|^2$ as $z\times \bar z$, but I didn't get to any result. Can you help me?

Comment: @Macavity: It is the identical question from the same author. – As I understand it (correct me if I am wrong) a question which is "on hold" should be edited and improved instead of just repeating it.

Comment: @MartinR Yes - that is the expected behaviour.  But perhaps it may not be known to new people, and it looked like Stefan edited his question, albeit by not much.

Comment: The yellow box clearly states: "If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question."

Comment: It is true that this question had been asked before, but it is untrue that it had already received an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "answer" is rather far from a complete answer. It only transforms the problem into a kind of conformal representation problem and makes remarks about the tightness of the minoration.

These indications and remarks can, hopefully, help other people as a kind of base camp before undertaking ascension to the summit.

$$|z|>1 \Rightarrow \left( \frac{|2z-1|^2} {7} \right)^{1/6}\ge \left( \frac {|z-1|^2} {3}\right)^{1/7} \ \ \ (1)$$

can be expressed under the following way

$$|z|>1 \Rightarrow \frac{|z-\frac12|^7} {|z-1|^6} \ge a \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ a:=\dfrac{7^{7/2}}{3^3 \times 2^7} \ \ \ (2)$$

Using the following notation:

$$Z=f(z)=\frac{(z-\frac12)^7} {(z-1)^6} \ \ \ (3)$$

The problem becomes: how can one prove that:

$$|z|>1 \Rightarrow |f(z)| \ge a \ \ \ \ (4)$$

Minoration (4) is in fact tight because $z_0=e^{2 i \pi/3}=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $|f(z_0)| = a$.

Another graphical indication of the tightness of relationship (4) is given by the figure below. This figure represents the image by $f$ of a narrow annulus $1<|z|<1.1$ as a kind of scarf rolled around the "neck" represented by the circle with radius $a$ (dotted curve). In fact, we have focused on the center of the "scarf" which turns some more times around this "neck": we have chosen not to represent these windings because they are at increasing distances from the circle.

Remark: my opinion is that a true proof of (4) will necessitate special efforts due to exponents $6$ and $7$, with $42$ as their least common multiple.

[image]